# Why i am getting default value of a after declaring a=b+c in my java code

Tags: java, class, object, variables, default-value

package abc;

public class Test {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    A n= new A();
System.out.println(n.b);
```

System.out.println(n.c);
n.j ();

```
}
```

}
class A
{

```
int b;
int c;
A(){
    b=3;
    c=8;
    
    
} int a=b+c;
void j() {
    System.out.println(a);
}
```

}

Comment: Pls format your code properly.

Answer (score 0):

This may solve your problem.

****THIS IS A WORKING EXAMPLE****

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    A n= new A();
System.out.println(n.b);
System.out.println(n.c);
n.j ();

}
}


public class A {

int b;
int c;
int a;
public A(){
    b=3;
    c=8;
    
    a = b+c;
} 
void j() {
    System.out.println(a);
}
}
```

Comment: Give a person a fish and they have a meal. Teach a person to fish and they can feed their family for a lifetime.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding `b` and `c` in your declaration of `a`.  So that arithmetic is done at the same time as the `b` and `c` (just after them) during the initialization of `n` the instance of `A`.

**The order of instructions when initializing an instance of a class is to initialize the field variables first, and then call the constructor** `A ()`.  It is not the order that they appear in the lines of the program.

So the sequence is to

```
enter the program at main ()
call the constructor new A ()
the "new" knows that it has to initialize the fields first
initialize b (to 0)
initialize c (to 0)
initialize a to b + c (to 0 = 0 + 0)
start running the actual constructor A ()
set b to 3
set c to 8
exit the constructor
return to main ()
print n.b
exit the program
```

Note that the value of a is computed outside of the constructor.  So adjust your placements so that the right order that you want is executed.

This kind of walk through the code is a really good way to iron out bugs.  Soon you will be doing it in your head like second nature.

Answer (score 0):

Put a debug point in
`int a = b+c`
you will know the reason. If something doesn't work, pls debug and see if it is taking you somewhere near the solution.

Answer:
Execution order is like this.
Instance variables are instantiated first, then follows the constructor.
Going by this, all the variables are not initialized to a value in your code, so default value of 0 is assigned to them. Hence "a" gets 0, even though b and c are assigned to a value later in the constructor.